# Generating a flag with available data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a table with the following , trying add a extra column/flag that gives the data in only two values (0 or 1 ). picture shows the expected result .Thanks in advance

```
--drop table #test 

create table #TEST (SERIAL VARCHAR(10),  DESCR VARCHAR(10)  )
  INSERT INTO #TEST
      VALUES ('12345' ,'TEST') , ('16782' ,'TEST1') ,
             ('46729' ,'TEST3'), ('82791' ,'TEST3'),
             ('72865' ,'TEST5')
```

expected results

[image]

Comment: How did you determine the flag?

Comment: How exactly this flag column is populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want half 0s and half 1s, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (order by (select null)) % 2 as flag
from #test;
```

This will give an arbitrary half of the rows a value of 1 and the other half a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create the table you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (SERIAL VARCHAR(10),  DESCR VARCHAR(10), FLAG BIT  )
INSERT INTO #TEST   VALUES ('12345' ,'TEST', 0) ,
                           ('16782' ,'TEST1', 1) ,
                           ('46729' ,'TEST3', 0),
                           ('82791' ,'TEST3', 1),
                           ('72865' ,'TEST5' 0)
```

If you want up update the table once it has been created you can use

```
ALTER TABLE #TEST ADD Flag BIT
UPDATE TABLE SET Flag = 0 WHERE SERIAL IN (12345, 46729, 72865)
UPDATE TABLE SET Flag = 1 WHERE SERIAL IN (16782, 82791)
```

Comment: This is the sample data, in real time data is created using some other process. i need to select the data from the table and create the flag for report purpose.

Comment: @Krisha How is the flag calculated